# Saving changes to database from WCF service not working

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, mvvm

I work on some hotel application. I have a listview in main window with hotel stays list. Listview have one checkbox column that is used to notify weather the stay is finished or not. Listview is also binded to property from view model. Checkbox is binded to command from view model.

This is the binding of listview

```
<ListView SelectionMode="Single" Height="428" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="lvStays" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="654" BorderBrush="Black" Foreground="Black" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MainGuests}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path= MainGuest}" />
```

**MainWindowViewModel**

```
 private ServiceReference1.tblStayGuest mainGuest;
    public ServiceReference1.tblStayGuest MainGuest
    {
        get
        {
            return mainGuest;
        }
        set
        {
            mainGuest = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MainGuest");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ServiceReference1.tblStayGuest> mainGuests;
    public ObservableCollection<ServiceReference1.tblStayGuest> MainGuests     
    {
        get
        {
            return mainGuests;
        }
        set
        {
            mainGuests = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MainGuests");
        }
    }

private ICommand _FinishedStay;
    public ICommand FinishedStay
    {
        get
        {
            if (_FinishedStay == null)
            {
                _FinishedStay = new DelegateCommand(delegate()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ServiceReference1.Service1Client wcf = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
                        wcf.FinishedStay(MainGuest);

                        if (MainGuest.tblStay.IsFinished == true)
                        {

                            MainGuests.Remove(MainGuest);
                        }                            
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine("working...", "MyApp");
                    }
                });
            }
            return _FinishedStay;
        }
    }
```

Here is the method on WCF service

```
 bool IService1.FinishedStay(tblStayGuest mainGuest)
    {
        try
        {
            context = new HotelBaseEntities();

            tblStayGuest stGuest = (from stg in context.tblStayGuests where stg.StayGuestID == mainGuest.StayGuestID select stg).FirstOrDefault();
            tblStay stay = (from st in context.tblStays where st.StayID == mainGuest.StayID select st).FirstOrDefault();
            tblGuest guest = (from g in context.tblGuests where g.GuestID == mainGuest.GuestID select g).FirstOrDefault();

            guest.IsCheckedOut = true;
            stGuest.IsMainGuest = false;
            stay.IsFinished = true;
            context.SaveChanges();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.StackTrace.ToString();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

What I'm trying to manage here is to change the value of **mainGuest.IsMainGuest** to **false**. It's value changes on wcf method but on FinishedStay command where im trying to do this:  MainGuests.Remove(MainGuest); the value of MainGuest.IsMainGuest is back to True. Also this value is not changed in database table.
Why is this happening?

Comment: What type and version of ORM are you using (L2S, EF4, EF5)?

Comment: I'm using Entity Framevork 4